# Power Method/PageRank in Matlab

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab

I am trying to implement PageRank using the power method in Matlab.

I start with a sparse $n\times n$ matrix $\textbf{A}$ where all nonzero values are $1$. $n$ could be very large which is why I am using sparse format.

I then normalize each column of $\textbf{A}$ (with the $L^1$-norm).

Next I apply the algorithm by constructing $\textbf{B}$ where (assuming no column of $\textbf{A}$ is a $0$ vector in this case):

$\textbf{B} = \frac{1-p}{n}\textbf{E} + p\textbf{A}$

where $p$ is a probability and $\textbf{E}$ is a matrix of all ones.

The problem I have is that now B is not a sparse matrix, but I am supposed to multiply B many times in order to do the power method.

I thought the whole point of the PageRank algorithm was to take advantage of the sparse matrix format, but now I have a full matrix.

So my question is, how do I multiply B repeatedly to get the eigenvector if it's a full matrix? How can I avoid constructing B and just deal with sparse matrix multiplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially PageRank is trying to solve the eigenvalue problem $r = Br$ where $r\in\mathbf{R}^n$, $\mathbf{1}^Tr = 1$, $r\succeq 0$, and $B\in\mathbf{R}^{n\times n}$ is the Google matrix you defined above.

Just doing out the matrix multiplication you get 
$$
\begin{align*}
r_i &= \sum_{j=1}^n B_{ij} r_j\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \left(pA_{ij} + \frac{(1-p)}{n}\right)r_j \qquad //\text{your def of B}\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n pA_{ij}r_j + \frac{(1-p)}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n r_j\\
&=\frac{(1-p)}{n}  + \sum_{j=1}^n pA_{ij}r_j \qquad // \mathbf{1}^Tr = 1
\end{align*}
$$
From the last line we can write the linear equations as 
$$\begin{align*}
r &= pAr + \frac{(1-p)}{n}\mathbf{1}\qquad \\
\end{align*}
$$

So the algorithm can be peformed as 
$$
r^{(t+1)} = pAr^{(t)} +\frac{(1-p)}{n}\mathbf{1}
$$
Note that $A$ is sparse

Answer (score 0):

You don't store $B$ or calculate $Bv$ directly. $Ev$ is just $\sum_iv_i$ times the all-one vector. So, to calculate $Bv$, you calculate $w=p(Av)$ first. Then add $\frac{1-p}n\sum_iv_i$ to $w$ entrywise.